# Ionic build android conflict with google services version

Tags: android, ionic-framework, build, ionic3

On running Ionic build android i am getting below error.

I tried to change the version of google services as 9.0.0 but after running build the version is replaced with +.

If this works i can release my app to the google store just stuck with this.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -- 
 debug option to get more log output.
 Total time: 2.265 secs
 Error: 
 /Users/User1/Projects/MinuteFormsTabsIonic/platforms/android/gradlew: 
 Command failed with exit code1 Error output:
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.

  > Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the 
  >   google-services plugin (information about thelatest version is 
  >   available at https://bintray.com/android/android- 
  >   tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updatingthe version of 
  >   com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or 
  --debug option to get more log output.

In Build.gradle file I have my dependencies like this

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:+"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:+"
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```